# How to use a nested scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my project, I have an Athlete model (inherits the User parent model), and it has_many :coach_contacts. In the CoachContact model, I need it to validate the uniqueness of its contact_type attribute, per sport_id, for each Athlete.

For instance, the maximum number of Coach Contacts an Athlete can have is unlimited (assuming an unlimited number of different sports existed), but the maximum number of Coach Contacts an Athlete can have **per each of their sports is two**. Not only this, but they must be of different types. There are two types of Coach Contacts, "school coach" and "club coach", and there cannot be two of one inside the same sport for the Athlete that owns these coach_contacts. So here is the Coach Contact model:

```
class CoachContact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :athlete

  validates_presence_of :name, :email, :sport_id, :athlete_id, :contact_type

end
```

And here is an example visual of a possible scenario of how this should work:

```
Athlete
    ->Football
        1. School coach
        2. Club coach
    ->Baseball
        1. School coach
    ->Basketball
        2. Club coach
```

However, it could NOT be this:

```
Athlete
    ->Football
        1. Club coach
        2. Club coach
    ->Baseball
        1. School coach
    ->Basketball
        2. Club coach
```

So how should I validate this in the Coach Contact model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can used a scoped uniqueness validator:

```
validates :contact_type, uniqueness: { scope: [:athlete_id, :sport_id] }
```

Comment: Isn't this going to only allow one per per athlete_id?

Comment: Shouldn't this be `validates :contact_type, uniqueness: { scope: [:athlete_id, :sport_id] }`

Comment: Yes, the other syntax didn't work, but meagar's did. Thanks guys!